# How to write the back end code correctly for this oracle package procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, oracle-sqldeveloper

```sql
PROCEDURE InsertCustomerEvaluation(
    cef_cust_id IN VARCHAR,
    cef_ce_id out number)AS
    cef_c_e_id NUMBER;
BEGIN 
  BEGIN 
    SELECT CEF_CUSTOMER_EVA_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO cef_c_e_id FROM dual;
    cef_ce_id:=cef_c_e_id;
    INSERT
    INTO CEF_CUSTOMER_EVALUATION
    (
      C_E_ID,
      CUST_ID,
      E_R_ID,
      SCORE,
      FILLED_DATE
    )
    VALUES
    (
      cef_ce_id,
      cef_cust_id,
      1,
      '',
      sysdate
    );
  END;
END InsertCustomerEvaluation;
```

Below is my code in back end.

```cs
public int InsertCustomerEvaluation(string CUST_ID)
{
    OracleParameter C_E_ID = new OracleParameter("C_E_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal);
    
    C_E_ID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    try
    {
        ce_id = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw
            ("DECLARE C_E_ID NUMBER; BEGIN CEF_APP.InsertCustomerEvaluation(:CUST_ID,:C_E_ID);:C_E_ID:=C_E_ID; END;", 
            new OracleParameter("CUST_ID", CUST_ID), C_E_ID);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return ce_id;
}
```

Do you have any suggestions to correct above backend code? It gives me -1 return. (Procedure works correctly in Oracle sql developer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `ExecuteSql` methods is not very useful, as it is by definition "the number of the affected records", whatever that means, so for SPs it's usually -1.

You've correctly defined an output parameter, now all you need is to read its value after executing the SP.

Something like

```cs
public int InsertCustomerEvaluation(string CUST_ID)
{
    // Define output parameter
    OracleParameter C_E_ID = new OracleParameter("C_E_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal);   
    C_E_ID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    // Execute SP
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
        "BEGIN CEF_APP.InsertCustomerEvaluation(:CUST_ID,:C_E_ID); END;", 
        new OracleParameter("CUST_ID", CUST_ID),
        C_E_ID);
    // Read the returned value from SP
    int ce_id = Convert.ToInt32(C_E_ID.Value);

    return ce_id;
}
```